# How to format date from json and set it into TextView

Tags: java, android, date

I am getting the json response as `"publishedAt": "2017-09-12T01:03:08Z"`
and i want to format this response in simple date like`Aug 12-09-2017 3:08`and set it into `TextView`
i am using something like this

```
Date dateObj = new Date(currentNews.getTimeInString());

TextView dateAndTimeView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date_and_time);
        String formattedDateAndTime = formatDateAndTime(dateObj);
        dateView.setText(formattedDate);

private String formatDateAndTime(Date dateObj){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy");
        return dateFormat.format(dateObj);
    }
```

Comment: what you tried so far ??

Comment: Please share your attempt in code.

Comment: Even if on Android you’re tempted to use the long outdated classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` (because nothing better comes built-in), I would certainly warn against using the deprecated `Date(String)` constructor. Still better, stop using those classes and start using [the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). To use it on Android you will need **ThreeTenABP**, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Thanks for the code. And welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way. You should also spell out how your code’s behaviour differs from what you want. If you see any error message and/or stacktrace, please quote them verbatim.

Comment: “Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include … a specific problem or error …. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." Quoted from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried `SimpleDateFormat`?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Something like (pseudocode, can`t test it here)

```
String givenDate = "2017-09-12T01:03:08Z";
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(givenDate );
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this method:

```
public String getDateFromUTC(String ourDate)
    {
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date value = formatter.parse(ourDate);

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa"); //this format changeable
            dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            ourDate = dateFormatter.format(value);

            //Log.d("OurDate", OurDate);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ourDate = "00-00-0000 00:00";
        }
        return ourDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

```
    String formattedDateAndTime = Instant.parse("2017-09-12T01:03:08Z")
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Nome"))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd-MM-uuuu H:mm", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

**Time zone is crucial**

As the code stands, it produces `Mon 11-09-2017 17:03`. However, please substitute the correct region and city for your desired time zone, and this will be reflected in the output. If you want to use the JVM’s time zone setting, use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`; however, be warned that other code running in the JVM may change this setting outside of your control, so it’s not perfectly reliable.

**ThreeTenABP**

I have taken my own medicine from my comment: thrown away `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. So the above code requires **ThreeTenABP**. All the details are in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**ISO 8601**

I am further exploiting the fact that the string from you JSON response is in ISO 8601 format, which the modern date and time classes “understand” as their default. Had it been in some other format, a separate `DateTimeFormatter` would have been needed for parsing it; but not here (with the outdated classes, two different `SimpleDateFormat`s would be needed).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" EEE dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
```